# Mock IHttpContextAccessor in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a method to get header value using `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class HeaderConfiguration : IHeaderConfiguration
{
    public HeaderConfiguration()
    {

    }

    public string GetTenantId(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Tenant-ID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I am testing `GetBookByBookId` method

Let's say the method looks like this:

```
public class Book
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private IHeaderConfiguration _headerConfiguration;
    private string _tenantID;

    public Book(IHeaderConfiguration headerConfiguration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor){
        var headerConfig = new HeaderConfiguration();
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _tenantID = headerConfig.GetTenantId(_httpContextAccessor);
    }

    public Task<List<BookModel>> GetBookByBookId(string id){
        //do something with the _tenantId
        //...
    }
}
```

Here's my unit test for `GetBookByBookId` method

```
[Fact]
public void test_GetBookByBookId()
{
    //Arrange

    //Mock IHttpContextAccessor
    var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    mockHttpContextAccessor.Setup(req => req.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Tenant-ID"].ToString()).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
    //Mock HeaderConfiguration
    var mockHeaderConfiguration = new Mock<IHeaderConfiguration>();
    mockHeaderConfiguration.Setup(x => x.GetTenantId(mockHttpContextAccessor.Object)).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());

    var book = new Book( mockHttpContextAccessor.Object, mockHeaderConfiguration.Object);

    var bookId = "100";

    //Act
    var result = book.GetBookByBookId(bookId);

    //Assert
    result.Result.Should().NotBeNull().And.
        BeOfType<List<BookModel>>();
}
```

But for this line:

```
mockHttpContextAccessor.Setup(req => req.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Tenant-ID"].ToString()).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
```

It says

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class. '

I was wondering what's the proper way to mock `IHttpContextAccessor` with header value?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use the `DefaultHttpContext` as a backing for the `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext`. Saves you having to set-up too many things

Next you cannot use `It.IsAny<string>()` as a `Returns` result. They were meant to be used in the set up expressions alone.

Check the refactor

```
[Fact]
public async Task test_GetBookByBookId() {
    //Arrange

    //Mock IHttpContextAccessor
    var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var fakeTenantId = "abcd";
    context.Request.Headers["Tenant-ID"] = fakeTenantId;
    mockHttpContextAccessor.Setup(_ => _.HttpContext).Returns(context);
    //Mock HeaderConfiguration
    var mockHeaderConfiguration = new Mock<IHeaderConfiguration>();
    mockHeaderConfiguration
        .Setup(_ => _.GetTenantId(It.IsAny<IHttpContextAccessor>()))
        .Returns(fakeTenantId);

    var book = new Book(mockHttpContextAccessor.Object, mockHeaderConfiguration.Object);

    var bookId = "100";

    //Act
    var result = await book.GetBookByBookId(bookId);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull().And.
        BeOfType<List<BookModel>>();
}
```

There may also be an issue with the Class Under Test as it is manually initializing the `HeaderConfiguration` when it should actually be explicitly injected.

```
public Book(IHeaderConfiguration headerConfiguration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    _tenantID = headerConfiguration.GetTenantId(_httpContextAccessor);
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean about the manual initialization of the `HeaderConfiguration`?  From what I can see, he is manually creating a mock for it and passing it to the `Book` class as I'd expect.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveBlack if you look at the original constructor of `Book` in the OP, they manually new up an instance of `HeaderConfiguration` and make no use of the injected `IHeaderConfiguration `. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: ah yes. I'd missed that.

Answer (score 6):

In my scenario I had to mock `IHttpContextAccessor` and access the inner request url bits.
I'm sharing it here because I spent a decent amount of time figuring this out and hopefully it'll help someone.

```cs
readonly Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> _HttpContextAccessor = 
  new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>(MockBehavior.Strict);

void SetupHttpContextAccessorWithUrl(string currentUrl)
{
  var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
  setRequestUrl(httpContext.Request, currentUrl);

  _HttpContextAccessor
    .SetupGet(accessor => accessor.HttpContext)
    .Returns(httpContext);

  static void setRequestUrl(HttpRequest httpRequest, string url)
  {
    UriHelper
      .FromAbsolute(url, out var scheme, out var host, out var path, out var query, 
        fragment: out var _);

    httpRequest.Scheme = scheme;
    httpRequest.Host = host;
    httpRequest.Path = path;
    httpRequest.QueryString = query;
  }
}
```

Comment: `_HttpContextAccessor.SetupGet(accessor => accessor.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext);`

Answer (score 3):

If you are making use of the wonderful NSubstitute package for NUnit, you can do this...

```cs
        var mockHttpAccessor = Substitute.For<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Connection =
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            }
        };
        
        mockHttpAccessor.HttpContext.Returns(context);
        
        // usage...
```