# Mock IHttpContextAccessor for local testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I have API developed using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and is configured in such a way a user must identify via Azure AD and retrieve token which I validate at the application level, and based on the role the user get some results back.

Currently in development environment I always need to authorize my self via Azure AD which time consuming , is there a way how I can mock IHttpContextAccessor  or other solution?

my start up class

```
...
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
```

the current claims I check

```
 public Utils(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
...
 private claims ExtractClaims()
        {
            Claims claims1= new Claims ()
            {
                OID = new Guid(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value),
                UserRole = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value),
                CustomerName = "Test"
            };
            return claims1;
        }
...
```

I would like to hard coded IHttpContextAccessor  with some data that I have in db. for token validation is disabled for dev environment.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916969/mock-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-unit-tests) should answer your question. All you need to do differently is place `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>` inside the else block of `if (env.IsDevelopment)`

Comment: I have seen that solution but I wasnt sure if I implemented correctly, since the return type I wish to have is  HttpContextAccessor while in that implementation the return type is mockHttpContextAccessor, is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: The return type is `IHttpContextAccessor`, the name of the return variable is `mockHttpContextAccessor`, but it's type is correct. You could call it `fooBar` or whatever, that won't change the type of it. In your case, you'd need `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(sp => new DefaultHttpContext())` inside the if development block

Comment: I got it maybe I didnt explain it well but this my method, `private IHttpContextAccessor mockHttpContextAccessor()` and return type `return mockHttpContextAccessor;` still create miss match between both types.

Comment: `return mockHttpContextAccessor` doesn't specify a type, the type is specified at the **declaration** of the variable `mockHttpContextAccessor`, you need to return `mockHttpContextAccessor.Object`. But your ASP.NET project shouldn't depend on Moq...

Comment: I see, im new to mocking so not so sure how to work around it. Thanks a lot this helped me out ;)

Comment: Mocking should only ever be used for UnitTests, and nothing else.

Comment: Then this wont work for me since its actually for testing in local env not meant for unit testing !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230635/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-ikenahim).