# Mocking RouteData for AuthorizationHandler Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, moq

I have an authorization handler in my web API project which needs to read route data (not query string). The code works perfectly fine, but I have hit a dead end trying to unit test it. Tried a lot of HttpContext mocking but nothing seems to give me the desired result.

**Edit 1**:

Ideally, when the test executes, I would want "httpContext.GetRouteValue("param")" to return "myparamvalue". That's what I get when I run the service and call the api using "localhost:8080//api/controller/myparamvalue/my-action" endpoint.

**API Endpoint** looks like below:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "MyCustomPolicy")]
[Route("{param}/my-action")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> GetResult([FromRoute] string param)
{
    return Content("Dummy response");
}
```

**Authorization Handler code:**

```cs
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
{
    // some other code
    string paramValue = string.Empty;
    if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        paramValue = Convert.ToString(httpContext.GetRouteValue("param"));
    }
    // more code that makes use of paramValue 
}
```

**Unit Test code:**

```cs
public async Task SucceedWhenCalledWithParam()
{
    //Arrange
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = CreatePrincipal("testscope", "scope");
    MyRequirement = new();

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString("localhost:8080");
    httpContext.Request.Path = new PathString("/api/controller/myparamvalue/my-action");

    AuthorizationHandlerContext context = new(new[] { requirement }, principal, httpContext);

    MyAuthHandler authHandler = new();

    //Act
    await authHandler.HandleAsync(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(context.HasSucceeded);
}
```

I have referred quite a few questions before raising this one. Some of them are listed below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566024/419556

[Mock IHttpContextAccessor in Unit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50916969/419556)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164807/419556

Comment: *"nothing seems to give me the desired result"* What *is* the desired result, and what happens currently?

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks for your response. I updated the original question with some more details.

Comment: Hi @Vinod, have you set breakpoint to your endpoint to check if any error? Did you pass the authorization successfully? Or just cannot receive the correct route value when the authorization passed successfully.

Comment: @Rena, Thanks. When I call the endpoint with postman, everything works perfectly. Authorization passes and API is hit as expected. Trouble is not with API execution. It is with unit testing. While unit testing I need to somehow mock the HttpContext object (which comes in as Resource property of AuthorizationHandlerContext) in the authorization handler.

Comment: The `[Route]` attribute on the action method determines how URL segment are mapped to parameters. Some internal mechanism in ASP.NET converts that information to routing data that your `AuthorizationHandler` can access (more specifically, the `GetRouteValue` extension method). You may read through the ASP.NET source code to figure out how to replicate information in a unit test, but this is likely to become a game of [Dependency Whac-A-Mole](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/10/02/dependency-whac-a-mole), as these things keep changing.

Comment: I recommend that you instead test such features by issuing HTTP requests against the service and assert that you get the right responses. Modern ASP.NET comes with good test APIs that enable you to self-host the entire service in a unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MarkSeemann. ASP.NET Core integration tests are definitely something I am looking at. I was just curious to see if this can be done at all with classical UTs.